# Use spin lock and lazy_static! on a static struct

Tags: rust

I was trying to create a mutable struct (an interrupt descriptor table) with s static lifetime. Since the `static mut` is not safe, I use an alternative of lazy_static and mutex like this

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use spin::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref IDT: Mutex<idt_type> = Mutex::new(...);
}
```

My 'idt_type' has a method which takes a static self as perameter like this:

```
impl idt_type {
    pub fn load(&'static self);
}
```

However is I try to use this method like this

```
IDT.lock().load();
```

the complier will complain since lock() returns a non static MutexGuard:

```
         IDT.lock().load();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^-------- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |     |
   |     creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |     argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

Is there any way to work around?

Comment: Why would the type take a `&'static self` rather than `&'a self`? The mutex won't ever given you a `'static` reference as that would imply you have locked the data forever, and thus don't need a mutex.

Comment: This is a function in a public crate. The function of the `load()` is to load the address of idt into the reg, and the idt should have a static lifetime. Anyway, I'm trying to find an alternative for `static mut`

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the abridged code you showed here, moving `Mutex` inside the IDT type will do the job:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use spin::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref IDT: IdtType = IdtType(Mutex::new(0));
}

pub struct IdtType(Mutex<i32>);

impl IdtType {
    pub fn load(&'static self) {
        self.0.lock();
    }
}

fn main() {
    IDT.load();
}
```

It is now your responsibility to implement the locking logic correctly instead of users of your crate. So it also has the added benefit of reducing the chance of misusing the API.